# SQLite insert on android works only once

Tags: sqlite, delphi, delphi-xe5

I'm with a problem on Delphi, i create a simple app to test the mobile power of RadStudio, I created a simple app that put some data into some inputs and then add it to database when button is clicked. I followed [this Embarcadero tutorial](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Mobile_Tutorial%3a_Using_SQLite_%28iOS_and_Android%29) as starting point

The problem is that I only get one entry added, then no more entries are added or the list is not refreshed. Below some code:

Table creation:

```
procedure TTabbedForm.logAfterConnect(Sender: TObject);
 begin
  log.ExecuteDirect('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS lista (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,idCons INTEGER,nome TEXT,kms INTEGER,kmsAlarme INTEGER,quantidade INTEGER,quantidadeAlarme INTEGER,data INTEGER,dataAlarme INTEGER,alarmeMsg TEXT)');
 end;
```

Add button code:

```
procedure TTabbedForm.btnGravarClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  try
    SQLQueryInsert.ParamByName('idCons').AsInteger := PopupBoxTipo.ItemIndex;
    SQLQueryInsert.ParamByName('nome').AsString := PopupBoxTipo.Text;
    SQLQueryInsert.ParamByName('kms').AsInteger := StrToInt(kmsEdit.Text);
    SQLQueryInsert.ParamByName('quantidade').AsInteger := StrToInt(qtdEdit.Text);
    SQLQueryInsert.ParamByName('data').AsInteger := DateTimeToUnix(dtaEvento.Date);
    SQLQueryInsert.ExecSQL();
    lista.Refresh;
    LinkFillControlToField1.BindList.FillList;
  except
    on e: Exception do
    begin
      ShowMessage(e.Message);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

If you need some more code snippet, please ask!

Thanks in advance for any reply!

Comment: Did you check if the Id of the insert isn't conflicted with the already existing data?

Comment: @RemiArts, the table is empty... The first insert works, but only the first...

Comment: Yeah but aren't you trying to put the same data in again? If the primary key is the same you can't insert

Comment: @RemiArts, I thought it could be the case, but i change all the data, and my table do not has a primary key, as SQLite takes care of it and the tutorial table don't have one too and works...

Comment: did you try my answer yet? For me that method works. If it works please accept it as answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this method it works for me

```
procedure TData.InsertItem(someObject: TSomeObjectClass);
var
  qry: TFDQuery;
begin
  qry := CreateQry( 'insert into SomeObject(id, description, something)'+
  ' values (:id, :description, :something);', false);
  qry.Params.ParamByName('id').AsInteger := someObject.id;
  qry.Params.ParamByName('description').asstring := someObject.description;
  qry.Params.ParamByName('something').asstring := someObject.something;
  qry.Prepare;
  qry.execsql;
  qry.Free;
end;
```

I've put and object in the parameter but you can also put the data you want to insert seperatly

Comment: Thx for the help, i was using another component, but with TFDQuery I got it to work. Sorry for taking so long, but only today i could work with the project again... Thanks again for the help Remi!